# secast init file already exists

Tags: security, asterisk, intrusion-detection, secast

I'm installing SecAst on a new computer and I'm on step 2.1.7 (copying init files).  I copied the first initd file, but when I copy the second one it says file already exists (and I'm overwriting the last file).  This doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've misread the manual...You'll notice that the instructions contain different steps for different operating systems.

You are performing the steps in the box marked "Red Hat 6" and the steps in the box marked "Ubuntu".  You should only be performing one OR the other.